# Generate Protobuf Python source with Meson

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, meson-build

Just learning how to use Meson and want to generate protobuf source/headers for multiple languages - C++, Python, Java, Javascript. C++ was simple enough using the generator function in my `meson.build` file:

```
project('MesonProtobufExample', 'cpp')
protoc = find_program('protoc', required : true)
deps = dependency('protobuf', required : true)
gen = generator(protoc, \
  output    : ['@BASENAME@.pb.cc', '@BASENAME@.pb.h'],
  arguments : ['--proto_path=@CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR@', '--cpp_out=@BUILD_DIR@', '@INPUT@'])
generated = gen.process('MyExample.proto')
ex = executable('my_example', 'my_example.cpp', generated, dependencies : deps)
```

Which produces the `MyExample.pb.cc` and `MyExample.pb.h` files. I figured Python would be just as easy but I'm a bit stumped since there's no executable() step for my Python script since it doesn't need to be compiled. I noticed meson (and CMake it turns out) don't actually generate the protobuf files until you call executable() so I can't just skip this step or the `MyExample_pb2.py` file will not be generated. I have found no example for using meson/python/GPB together after several hours of searching. Shouldn't there be a simple way to 'link' the generated sources to a python file/module like the way CMake does?

```
protobuf_generate_python(PROTO_PY MyExample.proto)

# This command causes the protobuf python binding to be generated
add_custom_target(my_example.py ALL DEPENDS ${PROTO_PY})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use trick with [custom_target()](https://mesonbuild.com/Custom-build-targets.html) and "fake compiler" in the form of **cp** or **cat** tools (in -nix environments, of course, if you want to support Windows then you can use conditional **find_program()**). Here is the example with **cp**:

```
py_gen = generator( ... )
py_generated = gen.process('MyExample.proto')
py_proc = custom_target('py_proto',
                        command: [ 'cp', '@INPUT@', '@OUTPUT@' ],
                        input : py_generated,
                        output : 'MyExample_pb2.py',
                        build_by_default : true)
```

I added **buid_by_default** flag assuming that you need to generate it as a part of standard build process (of course, enabling this target can be conditional too).

Comment: I don't understand how that solves it given that `.pb.cc' and `.pb.h` are generated, but here you specify the `output` as a single file. Also, how would one install the `.pb.h` into `include/` in the install prefix using this custom target?

Comment: @nh2 exactly, this just copies python file which addresses the problem in question: "... step for my Python script since it doesn't need to be compiled". The answer is not related to .pb.cc / .pb.h

Comment: Ah sorry, you are entirely right. In my quest to figure out https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/2451 I completely misread the question.